# Online shareable diary

Tags: windows, android, web-apps

I am searching for an share-able online diary solution, to live broadcast an event.

**The requirements:**

**Writer**:

- Upload entries from an Android mobile phone
- Each entry to be automatically time-stamped
- Attach/embed photos and possibly (small) video clips
- (optional) receive feedback via a comments section
- Share the entire story line using a unique URL or similar method

**Reader**:

- Read the entire story line by opening an URL in a browser
- No need to create and account or use an existing Facebook/Google+ account
- Not dependent on using a mobile device (phone or tablet)
- Enhanced capabilities (e.g. notifications of updated content) when using a mobile device (Android, iOS)

So far [Evernote](http://www.evernote.com/) meets most of the criteria (it does not have time-stamped entries) but is has an annoyingly small 50MB per month of upload quota. This is fine for text but uploading photos taken with a modern phone will burn it pretty quickly.

Alternatively [WhatsApp](http://www.whatsapp.com) user interface is ideal (time-stamped entries, posibility to embed photos and videos) but I cannot share a conversation with a group or with someone without a mobile device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating a site on [wordpress.com](http://store.wordpress.com/plans/) answers most of your requirements. The free version comes with 3 Gb of space and an additional 7 Gb costs 16 euros/year. With a blog, time stamps are automatic and Wordpress also keeps a history of edits and modifications.

The Android client is pretty good although editing can also be done from a web browser easily. You can keep the site private and invite only [some people](http://en.support.wordpress.com/adding-users/) to contribute or view the posts, or you can make it public and share the links.

Notification of updated content is also possible but it obviously requires some kind of logging in.

The only downside is that Wordpress includes ads in the pages for the free version of the blog.

Comment: This is not a bad option at all; A bit complex but it does the job. Main issue is the free package does not allow posting videos only text and pictures

Comment: I did not know about the video part, sorry. A solution could involve external links to a video sharing service. I only have experience with [Flickr](http://www.flickr.com) and the interface for sharing is [rather confusing](https://help.yahoo.com/kb/flickr/post-videos-photos-blog-sln15708.html?impressions=true). You can get a private link for a video posted on your Flickr account, and keep the videos private.